# Save mobile number in a file android

Tags: android, android-intent, try-catch, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have developed an android app that enable the user to register by his/her mobile phone number. I want my app to save the phone number so that next time the user open the app, there will be no need to enter the phone number again, analogous to Whatsapp..
Here is my code, but it doesn't work and I still have to enter the phone number each time I open the app, besides, after adding this code to my app, the app became so heavy and slow.

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
  {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    try {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String EE = e.getMessage();
    }
    if (mPhoneNumber == null) {
    try {
        fOut = openFileOutput("textfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        fIn = openFileInput("textfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[50];
        if (isr.read(inputBuffer) == 0) {

        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Warrning");
    alert.setMessage("Please Set Your Phone number");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            mPhoneNumber = input.getText().toString();
            try {
                fIn = openFileInput("textfile.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[50];
                if (isr.read(inputBuffer) == 0) {
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    // ---write the string to the file---
                    osw.write(mPhoneNumber);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                    // ---display file saved message---
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Phone number saved successfully!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // ---clears the EditText---
                    input.setText("");
                } else {
                    int charRead;
                    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                        // ---convert the chars to a String---
                        String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,
                                0, charRead);
                        mPhoneNumber = readString;
                        inputBuffer = new char[50];
                    }
                    // ---set the EditText to the text that has been
                    // read---

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Phone number read successfully!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            int UserServiceId = CallLogin(mPhoneNumber);
            if (UserServiceId > 0) {
                Intent Service = new Intent(MainScreeen.this,
                        RecipeService.class);
                Service.putExtra("UserId", UserServiceId);
                startService(Service);
            } else {
                Intent Reg = new Intent(MainScreeen.this,
                        Regsteration.class);
                Reg.putExtra("PhoneNumber", mPhoneNumber);
                startActivity(Reg);
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
    } else {

        int UserServiceId = CallLogin(mPhoneNumber);
        if (UserServiceId > 0) {
            Intent Service = new Intent(MainScreeen.this,
                    RecipeService.class);
            Service.putExtra("UserId", UserServiceId);
            startService(Service);
        } else {
            Intent Reg = new Intent(MainScreeen.this, Regsteration.class);
            Reg.putExtra("PhoneNumber", mPhoneNumber);
            startActivity(Reg);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to figure it out !!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this block of code:

```
if (mPhoneNumber == null) {
try {
    fOut = openFileOutput("textfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    fIn = openFileInput("textfile.txt");
```

you open the file for output, which will destroy anything that you've already written to it. Later, when you try to read from this file, it is all too late.

Also, you've got way too much code here. Don't reinvent the wheel. You don't need to read files a character at a time. If all you want to do is to write a string into the file and later read it back out again, use `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` and you can read/write strings directly using `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()`. Here's a simple example to r ead the file:

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(openFileInput("textfile.txt"));
    String contents = in.readUTF();
```

to write the file use:

```
    DataOuputStream out = new DataOutputStream(openFileOutput("textfile.txt", 0));
    out.writeUTF(phoneNumber);
```

Obviously you need to add the try/catch blocks and deal with exceptions and make sure you close the streams in a  `finally` block, but you will end up with a lot less code if you do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

To help you I give you my activity example in order to read and write data in a file:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class StoreDataActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "ExerciceActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        writeFileOnDisk("toto.txt", "Bienvenue chez Android");

        String content = readFileOnDisk("toto.txt");
        Log.v(TAG, "content=" + content);
    }

    private void writeFileOnDisk(String filename, String data) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String readFileOnDisk(String filename) {

        int inChar;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput(filename);
            while ((inChar = fis.read()) != -1) {
                buffer.append((char) inChar);
            }
            fis.close();

            String content = buffer.toString();

            return content;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```